# referenced before assignment error or no such attribute error in tkinter class

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI using Tkinter for loading certain files into a database, but I ran into a problem where, depending on how my code is written, I either get a no such attribute error for all the methods(all since I commented out others to check if any worked individually) I'm using in the Tkinter GUI, or `a referenced before assignment error`.  Which error I get depends on whether or not I have `command=self.acommand`, or `command=acommand`.  I may have done the button code wrong, but I was following an example given in a book that worked (albeit for a much simpler program).

The error I get is this when I don't have self (this is with the pick csv button code commented out:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 116, in 
>       main()   File "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 113, in main
>       db_gui=DBGui()   File "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 48, in **init**
>       text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=listalphabetical) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listalphabetical' referenced before
>   assignment

when I use this:

```
self.alphabeticallist_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=listalphabetical)
```

When I use this code instead:

```
self.alphabeticallist_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=self.listalphabetical)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 116, in 
>       main()   File "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 113, in main
>       db_gui=DBGui()   File "C:/Python27/databasetest1.py", line 48, in **init**
>       text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=self.listalphabetical) AttributeError: DBGui instance has no
>   attribute 'listalphabetical'

Anyway, here is the class definition I'm using:

```
class DBGui:
    def __init__(self):
    #Create main window widget.
        self.main_window = Tkinter.Tk()


        print 'window created'




#Button to open file dialog box.
    self.choosefile_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
                    text='Pick csv file', command=self.loadcsv)

#Buttons to use queries                                     
    self.alphabeticallist_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=listalphabetical)

    self.zipcodepaydatefilter_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
    text='Members with zipcode 22101 who paid January', command=filterzippaydate)

    self.statejoindatefilter_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='members who joined since 1999-07-01 and live in VA', command=filterstatejoindate)

    self.namemembersfavloc_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text ='Members and their favorite store+location', command=listmembersfavstore)

    self.membersfavtotalwine_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
                    text='Members whose favorite wine store is Total Wine', command=listmembersfavtotalwine)

    self.quit_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='Quit', command=self.main_window.quit)                                             

    #Pack the buttons
    self.choosefile_button.pack()                                   
    self.alphabeticallist_button.pack()                                 
    self.zipcodepaydatefilter_button.pack()
    self.statejoindatefilter_button.pack()
    self.namemembersfavloc_button.pack()
    self.membersfavtotalwine_button.pack()
    self.quit_button.pack()





    def loadcsv(self):
            filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
            if filename.endswith('Members.csv'):
                    cur.executescript("""
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Members;
                CREATE TABLE Members (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12);
                """)
                    with open(filename, 'rb') as csv_file:
                                    data_csv = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
                                    to_db=[(i['col1'], i['col2'], i['col3'], i['col4'], i['col5'], i['col6'], i['col7'], i['col8'], i['col9'], i['col10'], i['col11'], i['col12']) for i in data_csv]
                                    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Members (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)
                                    con.commit()
        #code for importing Members.csv into a Members table
            elif filename.endswith('Stores.csv'):
                    cur.executescript("""
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stores;
                CREATE TABLE Stores (col1, col2, col3);
                """)
                    with open(filename, 'rb') as csv_file:
                                    data_csv = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
                                    to_db=[(i['col1'], i['col2'], i['col3']) for i in data_csv]
                                    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Stores(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?);", to_db)
                                    con.commit()
        #code for importing Stores.csv into a Stores table
            else:
                   print('Not a valid file.')



    def listalphabetical(self):
        cur=conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Members ORDER BY 'Last Name', 'First Name' ASC;")


    def filterzippaydate(self):
        cur=conn.execute("SELECT 'Member #', 'Last Name', 'First Name' FROM Members WHERE 'Zip Code' = 22101 AND 'Dues Paid' LIKE '%-01-%';")


    def filterstatejoindate(self):
        cur=conn.execute("SELECT 'Member #', 'Last Name', 'First Name' FROM Members WHERE 'State'= 'VA' AND 'Date Joined' >= '1999-07-01';")


    def listmembersfavstore(self):
        cur=conn.execute("SELECT 'Member #', 'Last Name', 'First Name', 'Favorite Store' FROM Members JOIN Stores ON Members.'Favorite Store'=Stores.'Store id';")


    def listmembersfavtotalwine(self):
        cur=conn.execute("SELECT 'Member #', 'Last Name', 'First Name', FROM Members WHERE 'Members.Favorite Store' = (SELECT 'Store id' FROM Stores WHERE Stores.'Store Name'= 'Total Wine');")
```

Comment: why do you have self before your buttons? can you please post the error message(s) you are getting? as is what you have provided is not verifiable

Comment: @glls I added the error and what seems to be causing it to the post.  Do you need the whole program?

Comment: More code isn't needed, the code could actually be trimmed down to a fraction of what it already is for a MCVE. This question already has plenty of answers. `UnboundLocalError` questions are answered at least once a week if not more on SO.

Comment: make sure to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just to clarify, is the problem that it isn't minimal?  Or not verifiable?

Comment: try in your first command `self.alphabeticallist_button = Tkinter.Button(self.main_window, \
        text='Member Data in Alpabetical Order', command=listalphabetical(self))`

Comment: Actually got the problem fixed I think.  One problem I have now is that when I try to use the openfile button, it says it takes 1 argument but that I have provided 0....  Isn't the point of it to pick a file from a directory?  I didn't know you need an argument for that.

Comment: @shivan: no, that isn't right.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley The problem was the placement of the method definitions.